GitHub Actions automation schedule not working
I am trying to automate my Python script using GitHub Actions, so it runs at a specific time. It worked with
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

yet when doing it with
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: "*/1 * * * *" 

the code does not get executed, neather does a worflow start.
repo: https://github.com/jojo20071/auto2
thanks for the help
It worked with
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]


Are you trying to run it every minute? Github has minimum 5 minute trigger for schedules: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/writing-workflows/choosing-when-your-workflow-runs/events-that-trigger-workflows#schedule
